# R Rstudio use Git from from several computers (pull/push-buttons are not enabled)

Tags: r, git

I have problems using Git in RStudio on two different computers.
With `Computer A` I've created a repository on Github and I've cloned this repo with RStido in a directory `(New project --> Version control --> Git --> create project)`.
On the `Computer A` everything runs as intended, I can commit, pull and push.

This directoy (and the R project file) is stored in a cloud, so that I have also access from `Computer B` to the same directory and R project file.

But when I open the R Project from the cloud on `Computer B` the pull and push-buttons are not enbaled:

[image]

The following command in the shell gives me this message:

`git push -u origin master`

```
*myname*@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What can I do to enable the pull and push-buttons on `Computer B`?

Comment: `*myname*@github.com` indicates that maybe you have a different git user name in computer B than from computer A. You can find how to fix this using `git config user.name` (see `git config --help` for all commands). If it still does not work remove all on computer B and clone (again ?) your project on it.

Comment: I might be misinterpreting your question, but it seems you try to use the same cloud project from 2 pc's? Your GIT configuration seems local (computer A) on the other hand? Are you using another public key when using another computer? Did you link that key to your github account?

Comment: @cbo I didn't want to write my real name, so I wrote `*myname*@github.com`. But yes, on `Computer B` there appears a different user name

Comment: @cbo `git config  *myGithubName*` gives me this message: `error: key does not contain a section: *myGithubName*`

Comment: @Arcoutte How can I check the Git configurations and the public key on my computers? I relatively new to Git.

Comment: well you could add a new developer `*myname*@github.co` in your github project. But your real name will appear there with every commit from computer A so ...
Or you use one unique user name.

Comment: The "GitHub-Name" on `Computer B` is not a real GitHub-name. It is just the locale computer-profile-name with a `@github.com` added. This name does not exist. Howcan I change the GitHub-name on `Computer B` to my real GitHub-name?

Comment: @TobKel I typically install GIT per computer, configure a public key per computer (within rstudio: tools- global options - GIT...) and link each public keyto my git account. This allows each computer to communicate with your github account. You connect both. Once you than have pushed the master from computer A, you can clone/pull it from the remote on computer B. The advantage of using GIT, is that you do not need the cloud storage of your scripts.

Comment: I solved this problem by connecting rstudio and GitHub with an SSH key